# How can I share files from iBooks with my Shared extension target

Tags: ios, ios10, ios8-share-extension, share-extension

How can I share files from iBooks with my Shared extension target?

I have next option in my Shared extension target .plist

[image]

I can open any files from iCloud Drive, Google drive and Dropbox with my application, but from iBooks app there is option to share file with my app. How can I fix this?